# Accordion via bootstrap in IE browser

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I connected the accordion script via bootstrap.
I implement this in the sidebar. If the screen width is large, then the accordion is not applied, the accordion is added on the mobile view.

Tell me, the IE browser swears at this script. Throws an error - an invalid character.

Where did I make a mistake?

https://ganzola.ru/elektrosamokat/

```
<script>

    if ($(window).width() <= 780) {
        $('#secondary').html(`
        <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                  <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    Фильтр <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
                    </button>
                  </h5>
                </div>


                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?>
                    <?php is_active_sidebar( 'shop' ) ? dynamic_sidebar( 'shop' ) : dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
                    <?php do_action( 'after_sidebar' ); ?>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        `)
    } else {
        $('#secondary').html(`
                <?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?>
                <?php is_active_sidebar( 'shop' ) ? dynamic_sidebar( 'shop' ) : dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
                <?php do_action( 'after_sidebar' ); ?>
        `)
    }


</script>
```

Comment: IE simply doesn’t support ES6 template literals … https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_compatibility

Comment: A good portion of ES6 is not supported by any IE browser. Edge does much better, and Edge 80 is literally a MS version of Blink/Chrome

Comment: @CBroe, @Machavity Thanks for the answer. If this script cannot be implemented on IE, then how can I configure the mapping on IE?

For example, this code should be taken into account for all browsers, and in IE leave only content without a script:
`<?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?>
<?php is_active_sidebar( 'shop' ) ? dynamic_sidebar( 'shop' ) : dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
<?php do_action( 'after_sidebar' ); ?>`

Comment: Can nobody really help me solve this problem?